# How to create a button that deletes all field when reset button is clicked. The following code performs action instead of resetting the fields

Tags: javascript, servlets

```
<form id="myForm" action="firstjsp" method="post">
<table>
<tr> 
<td> User Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="userName"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="emailID"></td></tr>
<tr><td>New Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="userPassword"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Confirm Password: </td><td> <input type="password" name="confirmPassword"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address: </td><td><input type="text" cols="40" rows="5"  name="address"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender:</td> <td><input type="radio" name="radioGender" value="Male" >Male</td>
<td><input type="radio" name = "radioGender" value="female">Female </td></tr>
<tr><td><center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center></td> <td><center><button onClick="myFunction()">Reset</button></center></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementByName("myForm").(reset);
}
</script>
```

<--firstjsp is a servelt file. on clicking reset the program moves to the servlet program instead of displaying the same page-->

Comment: what do you mean delete all fields? remove them from DOM. Or just clear its contents?

Comment: `.reset()` not `.(reset)`, also there is no `getElementByName` function. It's `getElementsByName`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should reset all values in the Form to its defaults. No need for Javascript.
In order to work you need to place the `<input ... >` inside the same `<form> </form>` tag as the form you would like to reset.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Comment: please point in your answer where this code should be placed in order to work

Answer (score 0):

IT is working fine, try this once

```
<form id="myForm" action="firstjsp" method="post">
<table>
<tr> 
<td> User Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="userName"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="emailID"></td></tr>
<tr><td>New Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="userPassword"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Confirm Password: </td><td> <input type="password" name="confirmPassword"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address: </td><td><input type="text" cols="40" rows="5"  name="address"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender:</td> <td><input type="radio" name="radioGender" value="Male" >Male</td>
<td><input type="radio" name = "radioGender" value="female">Female </td></tr>
<tr><td><center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center></td> <td><center><input type="Reset" value="Reset" onClick="myFunction()"></button></center></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementByName("myForm").(reset);
}
</script>
```